# Execute a .jar in a Groovy script

Tags: java, groovy, katalon-studio

I'm creating a test case with Katalon Studio using the script mode which is a groovy script. I need that groovy script to execute a `.jar` that will be inside the Katalon project folder.

For testing purposes I created a .jar that creates a file named "the-file-name" and prints a message in the console.

I found a way to execute a command in Groovy:

```
def command = "git --version"

def proc = command.execute()

proc.waitFor()

println proc.in.text
```

This prints git's version in the Katalon console. So I guessed that putting "java -jar test.jar" would be enough but even though the execution seems to end correctly it also seems that the .jar didn't do anything. Just to be sure, I executed the same .jar using de Windows command line and it works perfectly. The file is created and the message written in the console.

When executing, Katalon console acts as if it was correctly executed. There are no error messages and execution is marked as successful yet the test file "the-file-name" is nowhere to be found and I'm not getting the `.jar`'s console output shown in the Katalon console as in the git command.

Comment: If you have code, please don't use screenshots to communicate it, but just paste the code.  It helps search engines to pick it up etc and it helps to write an answer via copy-and-paste too.  And as for your problem: check for the error code, and see if there is something on stderr.  Don't assume something works in your terminal it works also in different programs.  Environment/paths/... might be off etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a way to do it.

```
public class CustomKeywords {

    @Keyword
    def runBatch(String path) {
        def cmd = "cmd /c \"java -jar \"" + path + "\"\"";
        runCmd(cmd)
    }

    def runCmd(String cmd) {
        KeywordUtil.logInfo("cmd: ${cmd}")

        def proc = cmd.execute();
        def outputStream = new StringBuffer();
        def errStream = new StringBuffer()
        proc.waitForProcessOutput(outputStream, errStream);
        println(outputStream.toString());
        println(errStream.toString())

        if(proc.exitValue() != 0){
            KeywordUtil.markFailed("Out:" + outputStream.toString() + ", Err: " + errStream.toString())
        }
    }

}
```